# How to insert a script in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Good night guys, I'm doing a project for AOI Inspection PCB, I managed to reasonably get what I want to work, however, I was trying to pass this on to a GUI like Tkinter, and it's difficult. Does anyone know if it is like or is it a whole new script? I'll leave the script I made. What I was thinking of doing, it was just having 1 main window, which shows the photos taken from the board (which will use a 'webcam' in real time), and check if the components are in position. If not, perform a warning function.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RlY_N8sqwG6IEfnoimMs1uUgoElV-amU/view?usp=sharing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import time
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('placas.mp4')

#img_counter = 0
#img_rgb = cv2.imread('placaboa.png')
#cv2.namedWindow('video')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 600), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print('Escape hit, Closing...')
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('w'):
        imagem = "placaboa.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(imagem, frame)
        print('{} Gravado!'.format(imagem))
        img_counter += 1
    else:
        pass

    #Azul
    match1 = 0
    threshold1 = 0.85

    #Bosa
    match2 = 0
    threshold2 = 0.85

    #Capacitor
    match3 = 0
    threshold3 = 0.85

    #Jack
    match4 = 0
    threshold4 = 0.85

    #Reset
    match5 = 0
    threshold5 = 0.85

    #Conector Bosa
    match6 = 0
    threshold6 = 0.85

    if match1 == 0: # Azul
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold1)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match1 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold1:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Azul ok')
                        match1 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break

    if match2 == 0: # Bosa
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold2)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match2 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold2:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Bosa ok')
                        match2 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break

    if match3 == 0: # Capacitor
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold3)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match3 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold3:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Capacitores ok')
                        match3 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break


    if match4 == 0: # Jack
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold4)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match4 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold4:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Jack ok')
                        match4 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break

    if match5 == 0: # Reset
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold5)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match5 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold5:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Reset ok')
                        match5 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break

    if match6 == 0: # Conector Bosa
        template_data = []
        files = glob.glob('azul\*.png')

        for myfile in files:
            pc = cv2.imread(myfile, 0)
            template_data.append(pc)

        for tmp in template_data:
            (Tw, Th) = tmp.shape[::-1]

            res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where( res >= threshold6)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            top_left = max_loc

            if match6 == 0:
                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    if loc >= threshold6:
                        cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (top_left[0] + Tw, top_left[1] + Th), (0,255,255), 2)
                        print('Conector Bosa ok')
                        match6 = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Não Encontrado.')
                        break
                    break
            else:
                break

    #------------------------------------------------#

    if match1 == 1:
        if match2 == 1:
            if match3 == 1:
                if match4 == 1:
                    if match5 == 1:
                        if match6 == 1:
                            cv2.imshow('Detected', img)
                            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                                break
                        else:
                            print('--- Conector Bosa faltando ---')
                            break
                    else:
                        print('--- Reset faltando ---')
                        break
                else:
                    print('--- Jack faltando ---')
                    break
            else:
                print('--- Capacitor faltando ---')
                break
        else:
            print('--- Bosa faltando ---')
            break
    else:
        print('--- Azul faltando ---')
        break
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Anyway to do this 'simple'?

Comment: The google drive link doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: @TheMaker, now its working, try again please. Thank you

Comment: @Leonardo, please be more clear. Are you getting an error? If so, then ask your question on StackOverflow. Otherwise, the question is not the type of question to be asked. In other words, SO is not a tutorial resource. Thanks!